# How to access the Class of the Activity defined in parentActivityName

Tags: android

For every activity which has a logical parent we define that parent Activity in the Manifest like so:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_title"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.activity.ParentActivity"
        android:theme="@style/My.Theme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ui.activity.ParentActivity" />
</activity>
```

Is there a way to access the Class referenced in either `@parentActivityName` or `meta-data@value` in MyActivity?
(Please note that I don't want to access the parent Activity instance, just the Class)

The reason is that for tracking purposes we want to generate a path-like String for each Activity. In this case this String would be `/parent_activity/my_activity` – and since the hierachy is already defined in the Manifest, best case would be to access it there then to define it twice.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it will help you `NavUtils.getParentActivityName(childActivityInstance)`

Comment: Yes that helped, thank you! I can not directly use this method though because childActivity is an object, not a class (and thus this would not work for hierachies that are deeper then two levels). BUT I will try to use [the old implementation of that method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/c9cf2eb0a9b6694d0fda3dbc313844955db60820/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.java#182) as reference to walk through the hierachy recursively based on the class/component name. Will try and report back.

Comment: This did the job. I used `NavUtils.getParentActivityName(Context, ComponentName)` and created the `ComponentName` with the app context and the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go with the easy way: Pass the parent activity name in intent extras as string, in ParentActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ParentActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("parent_activity_name", "ParentActivity");
...
startActivity(intent);
```

And then get it in the ChildActivity activity

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String parentName = intent.getStringExtra("parent_activity_name");
```

Not sure if there is any other more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The problem with this approach is that this would be the parent activity from the activity stack, not the parent in the activity hierachy as defined by the manifest, right? (I know I could just hardcode the information about the manifest-parent in each activity, that just means I'd have to define this information twice [in the Manifest and then again in each Activity]).